# Fastest way to deserialize multiple json strings using Json.NET

Tags: c#, json.net

I will be retrieving multiple blocks of json data over time and deserializing them using Json.NET. I have objects created that mirror the structure of each different block of data, but when each block is received I will not be able to detect the type.

I would like to avoid attempting deserialization for each type, catching the failures (when exceptions are thrown) and moving on to the next type. Doing so would obviously be bad for performance.

Is there a fast and efficient way to determine the structure of a json message and deserialize it? Would the only way to use `(JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(...)` then drill into the structure to check if certain children exist, then using `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(...)`? It seems deserializing the object twice is inefficient.

Comment: Is the producer of this JSON able to make changes to meet your needs?

Comment: No. The JSON structures must stay as they are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the impression, even before I posted the question, that there wasn't an obviously more elegant way to handle this scenario. I've decided to do the double deserialization. I don't think it's ideal, but I guess there isn't a better/cleaner way out there yet.

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

You stated that trial-and-error deserializing "would obviously be bad for performance." Have you measured this? Does the deserializer take very long to determine it's got the wrong type? It may be inelegant, but may not be that expensive.

Depending upon your measurements, you might be able to do a partial string comparison of the beginning of your JSON data and branch to the correct type, with a trial-and-error as a fallback.

However, you might find that if you try deserializing by the type most likely to occur, then you might find it fast *enough* without having to do extra comparisons.

Comment: I haven't gone out of my way to measure performance and it may not be expensive, but my code is for a library, so it could potentially be used in scenarios that hit the code very frequently, so I'm looking to cut it down as much as possible. This question was really looking for ideas, more so than addressing a known issue.

Comment: @Ricky - Since you need to know the type to deserialize into, you're stuck either having to catch exceptions or examine the JSON string beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test this extensively but something like this should do the trick:

```
object MyDeserialize(string s) {
    using (var jr = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(s)))
    {
        if (jr.Read() && jr.TokenType == JsonToken.StartObject) {
            while (jr.Read() && jr.TokenType == JsonToken.PropertyName) {
                switch ((string)jr.Value)
                {
                    case "MagicKey1": return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MagicType1>(s);
                    case "MagicKey2": return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MagicType2>(s);
                }
                jr.Skip();
            }
            if (jr.TokenType != JsonToken.EndObject)
                throw new ArgumentException("Expected end object");
            throw new ArgumentException("Couldn't determine object type");
        }
        else
            throw new ArgumentException("Expected start object");
    }
}

void Main() {
    var s = "{ \"MagicKey1\": [], \"b\": \"asdaasd\", \"c\": { \"a\": 5 } }";
    MyDeserialize(s);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Do you have control over both endpoints? If so, why not simply 'munge' the response to tell you which model to use?

```
SomeObjectModel|{SomeObjectModelProperty:'Value',AnotherProperty:'Value2'}
```

You split and determine "SomeObjectModel" is the Type to deserialize the remainder to.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't. I'm consuming someone else's data.